# Cross py2 and py3 way of checking for tuple type?

Tags: python, tuples, six

It seems that six library does not have a tuple type definition and I am currently looking to write the code below in a way that works with both Python 2 and Python 3.

```
return (type(key) in (types.TupleType, types.ListType)
```

PS. Don't blame me for that line, I only try to port it, is not written by me ;)

Answer (score 4):

The best way would be:

```
return isinstance(key, (tuple, list))
```

This is simple, direct, clear, works in both 2.x and 3.x, and properly handles subclasses.